# Nested condition in different Panda Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am working on a variant calling Format(.vcf) file. Based on my analysis I need to implement a condition like :
I have two different panda data frame which are extracted from .vcf file

1. Diseases

| SNP | EfectSize | MinorAlleFrequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rs05 | 0.32 | 0.09 |
| rs012 | 0.5 | 0.20 |
| rs02 | 0.8 | 0.29 |

2.IndividualSNPs

| SNP | cola | colb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rs02 | 0 | 1 |
| rs03 | 1 | 1 |
| rs12 | 0 | 0 |

my condition will be like: if number 1.dataframe (Diseases) column 'SNP' is match with number 2. dataframe (individualSNPs) column 'SNP'. then I will check from individualSNPs dataframe cola and colb column.

if( cola=0 and colb=0):
score = MinorAlleFrequency* effectSize (from datafram Diseases of matched row)

if( cola=0 and colb=1) or (cola=1 and colb=1):
score = (1 - MinorAlleFrequency)* effectSize (from datafram Diseases of matched row)

then the score value will save in a CSV file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: rs012 appears in df1 but not in df2. Should the row be excluded or if not what should the score value be? Also what should the score be if cola=1 and colb=0?

Comment: @Henry Ecker ...Thank you for your response. Yes, rs012 is not in df2.It is not necessary to have same rs number in both dataframe.my question was if rs number of first dataframe matched with 2nd  dataframe rs number then I will check cola and colb of 2nd dataframe. In my case I am not considering right now cola =1 and colb=0.